# How to find this file in my local computer?

Tags: java, maven

I am using an open source Maven project and it runs fine. I was looking at this code and want to find out where the model file "/models/en-sent.bin" is located. I think it should have been downloaded onto my computer when the Maven project is built. I tried to search it using my Widows search box, but can't find this file on my local computer. Maybe it is because the maven project is packaged into a Jar file,which contains this file but i can't search it?

```
public static AnalysisEngineDescription getDescription() throws ResourceInitializationException {
    return AnalysisEngineFactory.createPrimitiveDescription(SentenceAnnotator.class, PARAM_SENTENCE_MODEL_PATH, 
            ParamUtil.getParameterValue(PARAM_SENTENCE_MODEL_PATH, "/models/en-sent.bin"), 
            PARAM_WINDOW_CLASS_NAMES, ParamUtil.getParameterValue(PARAM_WINDOW_CLASS_NAMES, null));
}
```

Comment: It's probably just part of the full path, but I don't think you can tell without going through the code inside `ParamUtil`. What's the value of `PARAM_SENTENCE_MODEL_PATH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does not search inside zip files and jar by default. To enable that you could go to.

**start menu>indexing options>advanced >file types>index properties and file contents**

Be warned, this might take a very long time to build the index.

Comment: Does that mean the "/models/en-sent.bin" is actually packaged in the jar file?